# Were we successful in Styx: Master of Shadows?

Tags: video-games

In the end of Styx: Master of Shadows we succeed in

> freeing ourselves from Styx influence, and killing him.

but it seems we are unsuccessful on many levels

> Aaron escapes.
>  The tree, and the tower, are destroyed. Since they are what kept peace between elves and men, this will likely spark war. Aaron escaping will surely be a catalysator for that as well, since he seems to hate elves.
>  We lose our memories, or potentially even died.

It seems like we failed our task, at least when it comes to the

> state of the rest of the world, outside of our own ego. We are at peace with ourselves, but at the price of an important city-fortress being in ruins, and having forgotten everything.

Is this what the plot is telling us? Is this expanded upon in Shards of Darkness (which I haven't played yet).